# Get attribute values from parent element - just by sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

- I have one table with employees.
- Every employee can have one boss/parent (but can also be null).
- Every top level employee has an value in the column floor.
- All his children inherit this 
  value in the code, but not in the datebase.

**Example:**

```
| id    | name    | parent_id | floor    |
|----------------------------------------|
| 1     | boss1   | null      | green    | 
| 2     | emp1    | 1         | null     |
| 3     | boss2   | null      | blue     |
| 4     | emp3    | 3         | null     |
| 5     | emp4    | 2         | null     |
```

Now I would like to answer for example the question, which employees work on the green floor (obvious answer: boss1, emp1 and emp4)? I know it's easy programatically, but I would like to do it only using SQL (Postgres).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [recursive common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to go through the tree. You also need to "carry" non-null values from the parent to the children to simulate the inheritance of the values.

```
with recursive tree as (
   select id, name, parent_id, floor
   from employees
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.name, c.parent_id, coalesce(c.floor, p.floor) as floor
   from employees c 
     join tree p on p.id = c.parent_id
)
select *
from tree;
```

Given your sample data, the above returns:

```
id | name  | parent_id | floor
---+-------+-----------+------
 1 | boss1 |           | green
 3 | boss2 |           | blue 
 2 | emp1  |         1 | green
 4 | emp3  |         3 | blue 
 5 | emp4  |         2 | green
```

Now this can be changed to return all rows with the green floor by adding a `WHERE` condition to the final select.

```
with recursive tree as (
   ... as above ...
)
select *
from tree
where floor = 'green';
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/UQJVF54349

Comment: I think you should put the filtering for `green` in the anchor part of the CTE.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: what if the boss works on a different floor than his/her employees?

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name! Works perfectly fine.